# What is Hydroxy Methylbutyrate-Ca and what is it's relation to butyric acid

Tags: everyday-chemistry

First of all, I am nowhere near familiar with chemistry. But I really need help with this question. A certain product contains "Hydroxy Methylbutyrate-Ca" and I need to translate this ingredient in two languages (German and Dutch). After some research I found it very unclear what exactly I am dealing with.

The first thing I found was "beta-Hydroxy beta-methylbutyric acid" $\ce{C5H10O3}$. According to Wikipedia this has a form with calcium:

> calcium β-hydroxy β-methylbutyrate monohydrate (HMB-Ca, CaHMB).

Would this calcium form still be considered "Hydroxy Methylbutyrate-Ca"?

The Dutch wiki named the same page "3-hydroxy-3-methylbutaanzuur". "Butaanzuur" would translate(NL > GB) to "Butanoic acid". Is "Butanoic acid" the same thing as "Butyrate" and "Butyric acid"? According to the Dutch wiki 3-hydroxy-3-methylbutaanzuur did have the same composition ($\ce{C5H10O3}$).

Someone told me "Hydroxy Methylbutyrate-Ca" would also be known as "Butyric acid". Someone else told me it turns into Butyric acid once broken down inside the body. What would be correct?

My main goal here is to translate "Hydroxy Methylbutyrate-Ca" but all resources I found have all kinds of names for this substance and I am completely lost. I'm not even sure if some of the dutch equivalents are talking about the same thing as their English counterparts.

My apologies if this is the wrong place to ask for help.

Comment: The suffix "*-ate*" refers to an oxoanionic entity, so "Hydroxy Methylbutyrate-Ca" is definitely not "Butyric acid". Calcium β-hydroxy β-methylbutyrate looks adequate to me. I personally would just directly translate anionic part of Hydroxy Methylbutyrate-Ca into the corresponding language, e.g. **Hydroxymethylbutyrat-Ca** (German) and **Hydroxymethylbutyraat-Ca** (Dutch), and call it a day.